# Search based on unique values in a Column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with two columns as below. I want to print the value in a 3rd column as True, if for same value in the column "Unique Value" it compares the corresponding value in Column "Status" & if the value in "Status Column" is Yes for all the similar unique values. What formula can be used in Excel to achieve  this.

Eg:- For Unique Value 1, there is Yes, No & Maybe, hence the value for it in Column 3 should be False, For Unique Value 2 there is only Yes & hence the value in Column 3 should be True.

Status      |Unique Value
Yes         |   1
Yes         |   1
May be      |   1
Yes         |   1
No          |   1
Yes         |   2
Yes         |   2
No          |   3
Yes         |   3
May be      |   3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed your explanation, then this works:

```
IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$10,B1)=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$10,B1,$A$1:$A$10,"Yes"),TRUE,"")
```

See:
[image]

If you want a separate list of "targets" then this version works where cells D1 to d5 contain the targets:

=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$10,D1)>0,IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$10,D1)=COUNTIFS($B$1:$B$10,D1,$A$1:$A$10,"Yes"),TRUE,""),"")

See:
[image]